# Remove links under main page

Tags: 7

When I add a new 'Basic Page' or an 'Article', a link to the Home page appears under the 'Main Menu' and I have no idea how to remove it.

[image]

How can I remove these links?

Comment: you need to check on page.tpl.php on theme folder.

Comment: @Smalution I have looked at the code, but can't seem to locate the code that is responsible for the creation of the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links are navigation links, so called "breadcrumbs". They inform the site visitors where they are on the site.

You are using the Bartik core theme -- take a look at `/sites/themes/bartik/templates` -- there is a file `page.tpl.php`. On about line 176 the following code

```
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

renders these breadcrumbs.

You *could* comment or remove these lines to avoid rendering navigation links. If you make changes to theme files remember to flush cache to see the changes.

But a better solution would be to create a Bartik subtheme (because each time you update the Drupal core, all your changes made to this file will be overridden, I would also not recommend to touch core files).

You could consider to choose another [theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_theme) which has additional settings options like for displaying breadcrumbs.